# How to check the footprint of a running task in vxworks?

Tags: target, vxworks

I would like to know of any commands or utilities there are to check the runtime footprint of application in vxworks (target board).

And I'd also like to know how to find the CPU usage of target board.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure what you mean by "runtime footprint", but the ti command will show you the stack usage for a particular task:

```
-> ti tNet0

  NAME         ENTRY       TID    PRI   STATUS      PC       SP     ERRNO  DELAY
----------  ------------ -------- --- ---------- -------- -------- ------- -----
tNet0       ipcomNetTask 1040fad0  50 PEND       1014c42b 1078ff10       0     0

full task name : tNet0
task entry     : ipcomNetTask
process        : kernel
options        : 0x9007
VX_SUPERVISOR_MODE  VX_UNBREAKABLE      VX_DEALLOC_STACK    VX_DEALLOC_TCB     
VX_DEALLOC_EXC_STACK

STACK      BASE     END       SP      SIZE    HIGH   MARGIN
--------- -------- -------- -------- ------- ------- -------
execution 10790000 10780000 1078ff10   65536    2404   63132
exception 10428fb8 10426030            12168     360   11808
```

For cpu usage, enable INCLUDE_SPY in your BSP and execute spy to start the display of the cpu usage:

```
->spy 
    NAME         ENTRY       TID      PRI   total % (ticks)  delta % (ticks)
------------ ------------ ----------  ---   ---------------  ---------------
tJobTask     0x10098410   0x103eeb00    0     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tExcTask     0x10097880   0x101d6560    0     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tLogTask     logTask      0x103efa58    0     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tShell0      shellTask    0x1058c5c8    1     0% (       2)    0% (       2)
tWdbTask     0x10141e80   0x104ae950    3     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tSpyTask     spyComTask   0x1042ecb8    5     0% (       8)    0% (       2)
ipcom_tickd  0x10060090   0x1058fb50   20     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tVxdbgTask   0x10051810   0x104ae658   25     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tAioIoTask1  aioIoTask    0x1040df78   50     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tAioIoTask0  aioIoTask    0x1040e3a0   50     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tNet0        ipcomNetTask 0x1040fad0   50     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
ipcom_syslog 0x10055190   0x1042e5a8   50     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tNetConf     0x100887e0   0x1044f8b8   50     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
tAioWait     aioWaitTask  0x1040aa40   51     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
KERNEL                                        0% (       0)    0% (       0)
INTERRUPT                                     0% (       0)    0% (       0)
IDLE                                         99% (    2495)   99% (     498)
TOTAL                                        99% (    2505)   99% (     502)

->spyStop
```